# Open Sets and Sequence Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$, and $x \in X$. Show that:
>
> $x_n \rightarrow x$ w.r.t. $d$ $\iff$ for every $U \subseteq X$ open in $(X, d)$ with $x \in U$, a final part of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ lives in $U$

I think I have an idea of how to prove $\implies$, but I'm a bit iffy on proving the other direction. This is what I was thinking:

$U$ is an open set; this means every point $u \in U$ has some neighborhood $N_r (u)$ s.t. $N_r (u) \subseteq U$. Now, we know that a final part of the sequence $S$ lives inside $U$. Does this mean we can take some neighborhood around the final part $S$? If a final part of $S$ living inside $U$, then doesn't that mean the convergence point needs to live inside $U$ as well, since the final part needs to become "final-er" and "final-er"? How should I draw the connection between final parts and open sets? I'd appreciate any help in seeing the connection between final parts of sequences and open sets. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\implies$ Let $U$ be an open set such that $x\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is a $r>0$ such that $N_r(x)\subset U$. And you know that $x_n\in N_r(x)$ if $n$ is large enough. Therefore $x_n\in U$ if $n$ is large enough.

$\Longleftarrow$ Let $r>0$. Then $N_r(x)$ is an open set and therefore there is a natural $p$ such that $n\geqslant p\implies x_n\in N_r(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The sequence 1/n, n in N, stays within (0,1),
converges to 0 and the convergent point 0 is not in (0,1).